# How do I get a .USDZ file to automatically open in iOS quicklook without the need to click on an image

Tags: django, augmented-reality, usdz

I am currently serving my .USDZ model from django and have the following view.

```
def download(request, id):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'files/{0}.usdz'.format(id))
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="model/usd")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

This page is accessed through a QR code but when the code is scanned with an i-phone the page opens and displays an image of a 3D cube. The picture then needs to be clicked in order to start the AR.

Is it possible to automatically start the quicklook AR without needing to click on the image?

Not sure if it would be possible with hosting the link on a page then using javascript to automatically click the link?